# End an input scanf when user press enter

Tags: c

for example i ask the user to enter two inputs,

```
int x,y;
scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);
```

i need a case where if the user enter ONLY one input and then press Enter(\n)
the program must say Missing number of input

any suggestions?

Comment: Use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`.

Comment: You can't do this with `scanf` alone.  (It turns out there's a lot of things you can't do with `scanf`.)  What you want to do -- this is a little more work, but pays of *so* handsomely in terms of infinitely better flexibility and error catchability -- is to read a line of text *as* a line of text, using `fscanf` or the like, and then inspect the line or break it up into fields or parse it somehow.  Sometimes, `sscanf` is a decent way to parse the line.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921431/c-fscanf-input-validation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it with your existing code where a single scanf statement is used to e ter both the values. Something like this can be tried:

```
void main(){
   int a;char b;
    printf("Enter two values\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    top:
    scanf("%c",&b);
    if(b=='\n'){
        printf("Missing value\n");
        goto top;
    }
    printf("I got all values");
}
```